# The request message is too big problem with office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I have a code that using to update the SharePoint list fields. the problem is the size of the request message that exceed 2097152 byte.I know Microsoft introduce a new approach in order to solve the problem but it is used for upload large file not for large request message.

My code is C# code as follow:

```
//Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
   ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
   List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// Assume there is a list item with ID=1. 
  ListItem listItem = announcementsList.GetItemById(1); 

// Write a new value to the Body field of the Announcement item.
listItem["TestField1"] = "This is my new value!!"; 
listItem["TestField2"] = "BigData1"; 
listItem["TestField3"] = "BigData12"; 
listItem["TestField5"] = "BigData3"; 
listItem["TestField6"] = "BigData4"; 

listItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

the problem the values of my fields is very big and I can not reduce it.
I have tried store each of fields in separate connection, but I faced a performance issue and some of fields is large(i.e the size of data that I want to store in TestField1 is large 2097152 .

it doesn't matter if the solution using javascript or C#

Thanks

Comment: 2097152 of what? Characters or Bytes? I think you are hitting the limitations for SP. Not sure SP Online but SP 2016 can have only 8000 bytes per row. REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I mean 2097152 bytes. The problem is not in capacity of the row,it is in the request message size (i.e body size in rest API in case I using the rest api)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Apart from asking SharePoint admins to increase the limit from 2 MB to something more, it looks like there isn't anything we can do using C# or JavaScript. Did you find any other solution?

Comment: @user841311 it's depend on your case, I have found a workaround with this by write all the data into a text file and upload the file into a SharePoint library, So I avoided send large requests. I know its a dummy way, but it is very useful in my case.